# How to partition collagen into separate fibers?

Tags: image-processing, morphological-operations

I have a picture representing collagen fibers of a tissue:

[image]

Image is binary consisting of a background (pixels with value 0) and white collagen (pixels with value 1). A zoomed in section of an image looks like this:

[image]

I want to find a way to partition the white collagen into multiple fibers,
so that I could measure the length and width of each fiber separately.

One idea was to perform a 
[skeletonization](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html) and then split the skeleton on every branch point. The problem with this is that the irregular shape of the the original collagen induces unnecessary branches in the skeleton: [image]

Here we see a skeleton composed of hundreds of segments, whereas the actual number of segments covering the "triangle" should be 3.

**Any idea of an algorithm that could partition such image into multiple parts?**

Answer (score 1):

Your data seems to be quite noisy in a sense that there are a lot of *holes* in the fibers. When you know a typical minimal size of a fiber (probably its widths), you could use a binary [*closing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)) filter:

1. Dilate the image with a structural element of the typical width of a fiber. Most likely a circle with a diameter equal to the minimal fiber widths could be appropriate.
2. Erode the image with the same structural element.
3. Use a skeletization algorithm on this data set.